# Problem with C language returning array pointer

Tags: c, data-structures

I am encountering this problem in every competitive programming platform that, whenever a pointer referencing to an array is returned from a function it returned empty, while printing in same function feels good. Take example of this 2 Number Sum problem:-

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int* returnArr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<numsSize-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<numsSize; j++){
            if(nums[i]+nums[j] == target){
                *returnArr = i;
                *(returnArr+1) = j;
                printf("%d %d", *returnArr, *(returnArr+1)); //working correctly
                return returnArr; //return []
            }
        }
    }        
    return NULL;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This parameter  int* returnSize is not used.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its not an issue

Comment: There are no other issues except a possible memory leak.

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [Your code works](https://godbolt.org/z/b0iSgK)

Comment: What do you mean 'returned empty' ?. Also, consider using 'calloc' instead of malloc  to get generic protection against random leftover data.

Comment: @dash-o Depending on implementation, `calloc` might result in a degraded performance, so using it blindly instead of `malloc` is not recommended.

Comment: I had added the image link please have a look at it

Comment: The image is not a replacement for [mcve]. Back to what @VladfromMoscow said - I assume that the function definition is given to you, but you are not setting `*returnSize` as the caller is expecting, so it doesn't know the size of the returned array. And it could be very well set to `0` by default.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok i modify it, and inform later

Comment: @EugeneSh. you were right Eugene... The problem is I didn't updated the variable

Comment: So, please, either write an answer and mark it to help others with a similar problem, or delete your question because it doesn't help others learn something. Just don't leave it unanswered, please, as it steels time reading through it only to find it answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the calling function doesn't know about the size of 
the returning array, and it is just looping for the **returnSize**, therefore we have to set the value of **returnSize**

Solution:-

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int* returnArr = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = 2;
    for(int i=0; i<numsSize-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<numsSize; j++){
            if(nums[i]+nums[j] == target){
                *returnArr = i;
                *(returnArr+1) = j;
                printf("%d %d", *returnArr, *(returnArr+1));
                return returnArr;
            }
        }
    }        
    return NULL;
}
```